# Why ModelBinding don't work with FormData but works with RequestPayload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have been working with Web API and found an interesting observation that I am not able to understand.

controller:

```
public class UserController: ApiController
{
   public void Post(MyViewModel data)
   {
      //data is null here if pass in FormData but available if its sent through Request Payload
   }
}
```

viewModel

```
public class MyViewModel{
        public long SenderId { get; set; }
        public string MessageText { get; set; }      
        public long[] Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

JS that is not working

```
var usr = {};
usr.SenderId = "10";
usr.MessageText = "test message";
usr.Receivers = new Array();
usr.Receivers.push("4");
usr.Receivers.push("5");
usr.Receivers.push("6");

$.ajax(
{ 
    url: '/api/User',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(usr),
    success: function(response) { debugger; },
    error: function(error) {debugger;}
});
```

JS that is working

```
var usr = {};
usr.SenderId = "10";
usr.MessageText = "test message";
usr.Receivers = new Array();
usr.Receivers.push("4");
usr.Receivers.push("5");
usr.Receivers.push("6");

$.post( "/api/User", usr)
.done(function( data ) {
debugger;
});
```

So, if I pass on `$.ajax` with lots of other configuration like `type`, `contentType`, `accept` etc, it still don't bind model correctly but in case of `$.post` it works.

Can anybody explain WHY?

Comment: what is the content type that you are seeing in case of `$.ajax` based request and in case of `$.post`? Note that content type is important for web api as it tries to use the correct formatter based on this to deserialize the request content.

Comment: content type is application\json, I want to know why it works for request payload and not for form data.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at what gets POSTed when you try it with `$.ajax` (e.g. with Fiddler of F12 tools of your choice). It can very well be that jQuery passes the data as URL-encoded string rather that as JSON literal.

To fix the issue try specifying `dataType` together with `contentType` parameter. Also, I don't think you need `JSON.stringify`, just pass the JSON literal you're creating:

```
$.ajax({
  data: usr,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  /* The rest of your configuration. */
});
```

Here's the TypeScript method that we use in one of our projects (`ko.toJSON` returns a string representing a JSON literal passed as a method parameter):

```
public static callApi(url: string, type?: string, data?: any): RSVP.Promise {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax('/api/' + url, {
            type: type || 'get',
            data: data != null ? ko.toJSON(data) : null,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: () => {
                resolve.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            error: () => {
                reject.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already did that. When you pass it through $.ajax it goes to request form data section but when you pass it through $.post it goes to request payload section

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani Not sure what you mean but just compare the two raw POST requests and you'll immediately see the difference. Also, I don't think you need `JSON.stringify`, just pass the JSON literal you're creating.